# Multipeer Connectivity through multiple view controllers

Tags: swift, class, multipeer-connectivity

What I want to do is have multiple view controllers where one connects you with another device in a multipeer connection. Then I want the user to be able to switch view controllers and keep that connection. I have researched this a little and what I have found is that I need to make a custom class and do all the multipeer stuff there. I found an example project that showcases this but there is just one problem, if the code is not in the view controller, how do I make an MCBrowserViewController.

Here is the code for the custom class:

```
import Foundation
import MultipeerConnectivity

protocol ColorServiceDelegate {

    func connectedDevicesChanged(manager : ColorService, connectedDevices: [String])
    func colorChanged(manager : ColorService, colorString: String)

}

class ColorService : NSObject {

    // Service type must be a unique string, at most 15 characters long
    // and can contain only ASCII lowercase letters, numbers and hyphens.
    private let ColorServiceType = "example-color"

    private let myPeerId = MCPeerID(displayName: UIDevice.current.name)
    private let serviceAdvertiser : MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser
    private let serviceBrowser : MCBrowserViewController

    var delegate : ColorServiceDelegate?

    lazy var session : MCSession = {
        let session = MCSession(peer: self.myPeerId, securityIdentity: nil, encryptionPreference: .required)
        session.delegate = self
        return session
    }()

    override init() {
        self.serviceAdvertiser = MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser(peer: myPeerId, discoveryInfo: nil, serviceType: ColorServiceType)
        self.serviceBrowser = MCBrowserViewController(peer: myPeerId, serviceType: ColorServiceType)

        super.init()

        self.serviceAdvertiser.delegate = self
        self.serviceAdvertiser.startAdvertisingPeer()


    }

    deinit {
        self.serviceAdvertiser.stopAdvertisingPeer()
        self.serviceBrowser.stopBrowsingForPeers()
    }

    func send(colorName : String) {
        NSLog("%@", "sendColor: \(colorName) to \(session.connectedPeers.count) peers")

        if session.connectedPeers.count > 0 {
            do {
                try self.session.send(colorName.data(using: .utf8)!, toPeers: session.connectedPeers, with: .reliable)
            }
            catch let error {
                NSLog("%@", "Error for sending: \(error)")
            }
        }

    }

}

extension ColorService : MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserDelegate {

    func advertiser(_ advertiser: MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser, didNotStartAdvertisingPeer error: Error) {
        NSLog("%@", "didNotStartAdvertisingPeer: \(error)")
    }

    func advertiser(_ advertiser: MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser, didReceiveInvitationFromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, withContext context: Data?, invitationHandler: @escaping (Bool, MCSession?) -> Void) {
        NSLog("%@", "didReceiveInvitationFromPeer \(peerID)")
        invitationHandler(true, self.session)
    }

}

extension ColorService : MCNearbyServiceBrowserDelegate {

    func browser(_ browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser, didNotStartBrowsingForPeers error: Error) {
        NSLog("%@", "didNotStartBrowsingForPeers: \(error)")


    }
    // This is what pairs:
    func browser(_ browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser, foundPeer peerID: MCPeerID, withDiscoveryInfo info: [String : String]?) {
        NSLog("%@", "foundPeer: \(peerID)")
        NSLog("%@", "invitePeer: \(peerID)")
        browser.invitePeer(peerID, to: self.session, withContext: nil, timeout: 10)
    }

    func browser(_ browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser, lostPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
        NSLog("%@", "lostPeer: \(peerID)")
    }

}

extension ColorService : MCSessionDelegate {

    func session(_ session: MCSession, peer peerID: MCPeerID, didChange state: MCSessionState) {
        switch state{
        case MCSessionState.connected:
            print("connected: \(peerID.displayName)")

        case MCSessionState.connecting:
            print("connecting: \(peerID.displayName)")
        case MCSessionState.notConnected:
            print("NotConnected: \(peerID.displayName)")

        }
    }

    func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive data: Data, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
        let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
        self.delegate?.colorChanged(manager: self, colorString: str)
    }

    func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive stream: InputStream, withName streamName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
        NSLog("%@", "didReceiveStream")
    }

    func session(_ session: MCSession, didStartReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, with progress: Progress) {
        NSLog("%@", "didStartReceivingResourceWithName")
    }

    func session(_ session: MCSession, didFinishReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, at localURL: URL?, withError error: Error?) {
        NSLog("%@", "didFinishReceivingResourceWithName")

    }

}
```

What I am used to when declaring a MCBrowserViewController is this:

```
let mcBrowser = MCBrowserViewController(serviceType: "doesnt-matter", session: self.mcSession)
mcBrowser.delegate = self
self.present(mcBrowser, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But I have no idea how I would do this from outside the viewcontroller

Answer (score 1):

You can make `service` a property of the view controller class.

This the service class is not designed to be a singleton from the snippet you shared, what makes sense here is to instantiate a service class for each view controller you'll present.

One important thing to keep in mind is: if you're going to be dismissing the view controller and re-presenting them, then you will have a maintain a strong reference (`let`) is some other class (the one you're presenting from, maybe?) so that the view controllers don't get de initialized and kill your sessions.

Let me know if this helps otherwise if you have more information I can edit my answer.

Comment: Can you give me a code example of this in referance to my code? Thanks

Comment: @Lolz4all- Have you tried building it yourself? If so, update the answer and I can help

Comment: well what do you mean by make "service" a property?